# Parse a string and use parsed value in predicate for subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a `symbol` attribute. I want to parse the `symbol` attribute for a certain set of letters I expect in a certain position of the `symbol` value, and compare them to the parsed value returned from a subquery. Here is my query so far:

```
select * from market_instrument inner join exchange_instrument on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id 
inner join Table1 on market_instrument.id = Table1.instrument_id 
left join Table2 on market_instrument.id = Table2.instrument_id
left join `options`on market_instrument.id = `options`.instrument_id 
left join Table3 on market_instrument.id = Table3.instrument_id
where symbol in (select symbol from market_instrument inner join fills on market_instrument.id = fills.instrument_id);
```

What this will do will compare the `symbol` attribute from the outer query to the `symbol` attribute in the inner query. A value in `symbol` looks like this:

`1FU_PLAT_1610`

I only want to compare a subset of that value. Can I do something like `...where symbol[1:5] in (select symbol[1:5] from market_instrument inner join fills on market_instrument.id = fills.instrument_id);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL [`substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187748(v=sql.110).aspx) function:

```
select * from market_instrument inner join exchange_instrument on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id 
inner join Table1 on market_instrument.id = Table1.instrument_id 
left join Table2 on market_instrument.id = Table2.instrument_id
left join `options`on market_instrument.id = `options`.instrument_id 
left join Table3 on market_instrument.id = Table3.instrument_id
where substring(symbol, 1, 5) in (select substring(symbol, 1, 5) from market_instrument inner join fills on market_instrument.id = fills.instrument_id);
```

Comment: syntactically can i do the same thing with a regex?like `where regex(symbol, pattern)...` i talked about position in my question for simplicity but it would help if what i am actually trying to parse is also possible to do with a regex.

Comment: @JeremyFisher Check out [`regexp` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: trying `...where symbol REGEXP '.' in (select symbol REGEXP '.' from ...) throws an error :(

Comment: I am using mysql. I just wanted to test if it would work with a REGEXP. The error message is simply that `you have an error in your mysql syntax` where the problem is with `in`. I tried `like` as well but it didn't work. if you know why that might be an issue awesome otherwise I'll make a separate question. you did answer the question I asked.

Comment: @JeremyFisher: No, it's not possible to use REGEXP to do that comparison, between a column and a set returned by a subquery. In MySQL, the REGEXP operator only returns a boolean.

Comment: @JeremyFisher I think you can't use both `regexp` and `in` operators, unless you use `and`. If you want to select `symbol`s which match your regex only in subquery, remove the first `regexp`.

Comment: ok thanks. i think i'll make a separate question about this to see what can be done